# Antlr repetition quantifier

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

Is there any ability in Antlr to specify the amount of repetitions, such as the regex operator `pattern{num}` ? As an example, I have something like:

```
tableItem:
    Identifier (DOT Identifier)? (DOT Identifier)? (DOT Identifier)?
```

And it'd be much cleaner if I could do something like:

```
tableItem
    : Identifier (DOT Identifier){0,3}
```

In a regex I would do:

[image]

Comment: Re duplicate -- sure, but I'd argue that the above notation is much easier to read than a nested parenthetical. Are there any advantages of using the nested paren approach?

Comment: A repeat operator for Antlr is noted in a Github Issue. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2577 and apparently elsewhere. It probably won't be implemented, but it is easy to write as a preprocessing step that refactors the grammar.